# Can I solve a system of massive linear equations faster if I know the solution to a system with the same matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the vector $x$ which is the solution to the linear equations $Ax=b$, i.e. $x=A^{-1}b$, can we solve the linear equations $Ay=c$ with the given $x$ so that we don't need to repeat the tedious process for calculating $x$ from $Ax=b$.

In other words, can we express $y$ as a function of $x$, $y=f(x, A, b, c)$. Note that $A^{-1}$ can't appear in the function.

Comment: Trying to better understand your situation. Do you already have computed such an $x$. Because using [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) in $A$ makes it easy to find a solution for any $b$ once row echelon form is achieved. Sorry if it does not fit your needs.

Comment: you said you already are given $x$, but why are you concerned to repeat the tedious process of calculating $x$ when solving for $y$?

Comment: How did you solve the original equation, how do you want to solve the new one? Is there any relation between $b$ and $c$?

Comment: Think about that if $A$ is a matrix of size larger than $1,000,000 \times 1,000,000$, then iterative method for solving $Ax=b$ will most likely be the only practical option. There is no relation between $b$ and $c$. If we have to give the relation, then they are linearly independent. What relations do you expect so that we can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you solved it.

Let's say one uses an LU factorization (with pivoting) to solve A x = b.  This means one computes permutation matrix $ P $, unit lower triangular matrix $ L $, and upper triangular matrix $ U $ so that $ P A = LU $.  Then, one solves $ L z = P b $ followed by $ U x = z $ to find the solution $ x $.  Now, since you have already computed $ P $, $ L $, and $ U$, you don't have to recompute them when a new right-hand side comes along.  And the bulk of the computation is in computing the LU factorization.